# The Electron.js app performs very slowly when using Selenium WebDriver on a Mac M1

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, electron

I use Electron.js to build an application that utilizes Selenium WebDriver to automate activities on Chrome. When using the application on platforms like Windows or Mac Intel, it works fine and stable. However, when using it on a Mac M1, it performs very slowly.

Here are the dependencies I have used:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "chromedriver": "^113.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.1.4",
    "electron": "^24.3.0",
    "electron-chromedriver": "^24.0.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.9.2"
},
```